# AudioFileWriteBytes is taking way too long to do its job

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, wav

This problem may be a bit too vast and nebulous for this space, but I'll give it a go.

I have an array of samples that I'm trying to write to a .wav file on my iOS and it is taking up to a minute and a half to do. Here is the loop where the drag is occurring:

```
for (int i=0; i< 1430529; i++)  // 1430529 is the length of the array of samples 
    {

        SInt16 sample;

        sample = sample_array[i];



        audioErr = AudioFileWriteBytes(audioFile, false, sampleCount*2, &bytesToWrite, &sample);

        sampleCount++;
    }
```

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT 1**

If it helps, this is the code that precedes it:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];




// THIS IS MY BIT TO CONVERT THE LOCATION TO NSSTRING
NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc]init];
filePath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:location];

// HERE I WANT TO REMOVE THE FILE NAME FROM THE LOCATION.
NSString *truncatedFilePath = filePath;

truncatedFilePath = [truncatedFilePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/recordedFile.wav"
                                    // withString:@"/newFile.caf"];
                                    withString:@"/recordedFile.wav"];




NSLog(truncatedFilePath);



NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:truncatedFilePath];



AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;


memset(&asbd,0, sizeof(asbd));

asbd.mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;
asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;


asbd.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;


asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 2;






AudioFileID audioFile;

OSStatus audioErr = noErr;

audioErr = AudioFileCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, kAudioFileWAVEType, &asbd, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &audioFile);

assert (audioErr == noErr);


long sampleCount = 0;
UInt32 bytesToWrite = 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need the loop ? Can't you write all the samples in one go, e.g.

```
    numSamples = 1430529;
    bytesToWrite = numSamples * 2;
    audioErr = AudioFileWriteBytes(audioFile, false, 0, &bytesToWrite, sample_array);
```

?

Comment: You are a genius! But now the playback is much slower (maybe half the rate?). Anyway, I'm sure I'll be able to figure that out (unless you have any ideas :). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the number of bytes you are writing at each call to `AudioFileWriteBytes` is too small. How large is `bytesToWrite`?

Comment: If you can't do what @Paul R recommended, you should probably use a larger byte buffer when writing the audio file (I don't work with iOS, but I've encountered similar problems in Java, C#, etc.). Your chunks are too small, so you have too many I/O calls.